# change a number of days to date

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan

how can i  change a number of days to (year,month & days) with DateTime class in C#
.actually i want to calculate the exact date of birth with the birthday.
? years ?month .... ? seconds .

my code:

```
DateTime a = new DateTime(1993, 6, 10, 0, 0, 0);
            DateTime now = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, DateTime.Now.Hour
                ,DateTime.Now.Minute,DateTime.Now.Second);
            TimeSpan b = now - a;
            int c = b.Days;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [NodaTime](http://nodatime.org/)

```
var period = NodaTime.Period.Between(
                new NodaTime.LocalDateTime(1993, 6, 10, 0, 0), 
                NodaTime.LocalDateTime.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now) );

Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4}",period.Years,period.Months,period.Days,
                                        period.Hours,period.Minutes);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no simple function for this that I can see. i.e. no way to do this with a simple DateTime function. If I were to put it in code, though, it'd look something like this:

```
DateTime birthday = new DateTime(1993, 6, 10);
DateTime current;
DateTime nowComparison = DateTime.Now;
int years = nowComparison.Year - birthday.Year;
if (nowComparison < birthday.AddYears(years))
    years -= 1;
current = birthday.AddYears(years); // current is less than a year ago.

int months;
if(current.Year != nowComparison.Year)
{
    months = nowComparison.Month + (12 - current.Month);
}
else
{
    months = nowComparison.Month - current.Month;
}
if (nowComparison < current.AddMonths(months))
    months -= 1;
current = current.AddMonths(months); // current is less than a month ago.

int days = nowComparison.Subtract(current).Days;
current = current.AddDays(days); // current is less than a day ago.

int hours = nowComparison.Subtract(current).Hours;
current = current.AddHours(hours); // current is less than an hour ago.

int minutes = nowComparison.Subtract(current).Minutes;
current = current.AddMinutes(minutes); // current is less than a minute ago.

int seconds = nowComparison.Subtract(current).Seconds;
current = current.AddSeconds(seconds); // current is less than a second ago.
```